# Added ListViewItem getting incorrect transform

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a vertical `ListView` using virtualization, and I subscribe to the `ContainerContentChanging` event. If I insert items into the top of the list, and attempt to get their transform in the handler for `ContainerContentChanging` using `TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content)`, as soon as the list has enough items to start virtualizing, I begin getting values like -15000 for the transforms matrix `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` values. Since I'm inserting the item at the top, it's clearly rendering (it has appropriate calculated width/height, etc.), so I'm not sure why the transform would be bad.

Here's some code if it helps. It doesn't get much more basic.

**XAML:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestListView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestListView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button
            Content="Add Item"
            Click="OnAddItemClick"/>

        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}"
            ContainerContentChanging="OnContainerContentChanging"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public readonly ObservableCollection<string> Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Items.Add("Test 2");
            Items.Add("Test 1");
            Items.Add("Test 0");
        }

        private void OnAddItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Items.Insert(0, $"Test {Items.Count}");
        }

        private void OnContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            var addedItem = args?.ItemContainer;
            if (addedItem == null)
                return;

            var transform = addedItem.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think CCC guarantees the full rendering & positioning of the items, especially when re-using an existing container. A quick test is to put `Task.Yield` in front of the transform calculation to push the latter to the end of the message loop.

Comment: @JustinXL Yep, that "fixes" it. I guess the moral of the story is to try not to perform transform calculations in CCC. Thanks.